# How can the mass of a Schwarzschild black hole be in its center and the moment of inertia be nonzero?

Tags: black-holes

A classical Schwarzschild black hole has all its mass in the central singularity. But it has a moment of inertia proportional to M^3 (in the small angular momentum limit of a Kerr black hole). Both results are found on physics.stackexchange.com .

How do these two properties go together? A mass with zero extension (in a singularity) cannot have a moment of inertia.

Does the moment of inertia imply that the mass is not concentrated in the singularity? How can this be, as in the Schwarzschild solution there is no other place for the mass?

Comment: A Schwarzschild hole does not have angular momentum. You must be talking about the limiting case of a Kerr hole as the angular momentum goes to zero.

Comment: An electron is a point particle but it manages to have angular momentum. The angular momentum of elementary particles and black holes is not as simple as the angular momentum of a rotating ball. It doesn’t come from masses moving in space like you learned about in Newtonian mechsnics.

Comment: Can you explain why you think these properties to be contradictory?

Comment: The singularity is not part of the space time.  A Schwarzschild solution is a vacuum solution, i.e. Energy-Momentum tensor is 0 everywhere.

Comment: A mass of zero extension (in a singularity) cannot have a moment of inertia. And yes, I was talking about a Kerr hole with angular momentum going to zero.

Comment: Moment of inertia is MR^2; if R=0, then the moment of inertia is also zero.

Comment: An electron has no known moment of inertia.